# How to change Highcharts data after creation

Tags: html, csv, highcharts

How do I change the display format after I have loaded the data for a highchart?

I have a program which outputs a CSV file. I cronjob the file to my webserver. There i create a highchart HTML graph.

I have 3 Rows and the data in row 3 is given in seconds. I want to display it in hours because sometimes it can be a year and this crushes my chart... so each value should somehow be divided "x/60/60".

I found some scripts which take existing data and convert it and put it back but i don't exactly know how to get them working without clicking an extra button.

So here is my simple start, maybe someone can help me. If i was unprecise please feel free to ask me

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>                    
    <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
             /*
                 Load the data from the CSV file. This is the contents of the file:    
                 Apples;Pears;Oranges        
                 John;8;4;5
                 Jane;3;4;5
                 Joe;86;76;79
                 Janet;3;16;13    
             */
             $.get('stat.csv', function(csv) {
                 $('#container').highcharts({
                     chart: { type: 'column' },
                     data: {
                         csv: csv,
                         itemDelimiter: ';'
                     },
                     title: { text: 'Deadlines' },
                     yAxis: { title: { text: 'Units' } }
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <!-- 3. Add the container -->
     <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried to make the problem statement clearer by removing the extra information

Comment: Please provide the sample of your data.

Comment: Sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n22ttn1htetyqz2/stat.csv?dl=0